# jQuery toggle & remove class not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple jQuery toggle class and remove class.

Assume I have 5 menu. Now when I click one menu then the arrow will set to down position.

Then now try to click another menu, the arrow down from previous menu is not back from the original position.

What I need is when I click one menu then click another menu then another arrow should back to the original position.

```js
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  var el = "<div class='click' style='padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;'><i class='fa-regular fa-angle-right'></i></div>";
  
  $(".menu").append(el);
}

$(".click").click(function(e) {
  $(".menu").removeClass("expanded");
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.2/css/all.css">

<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is `removeClass` from all `i` elements except the `clicked` one by `not` method.

```
$(".click i").not(iEle).removeClass("expanded");
```

Before `toggleClass` for `clicked` one.

```js
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
  var el = "<div class='click' style='padding: 10px; cursor: pointer;'><i class='fa-regular fa-angle-right'></i></div>";
  
  $(".menu").append(el);
}

$(".click").click(function(e) {
  const iEle = $(this).find("i");
  $(".click i").not(iEle).removeClass("expanded");
  iEle.toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.2/css/all.css">

<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, just now tried but when click the active menu(arrow has down position) it should back to original position also.

Comment: It is already when you click to arrow, it will go down and the other will back to the original position, please run code snippet and check.

Comment: I mean like this, try to click menu 1 then click again menu 1. The arrow down should back to original position. On your snippet, it's not going back to original position

Comment: I just update the code to include this functionality, please check again.

Comment: Working good now. Cheers